send a socket message by autohotkey v2
in v1, i can send a socket message(server: 127.0.0.1:65432), it works perfect...
but in v2, i don't know how to do it...
in v1, it's like:

#Persistent
#NoEnv
SetBatchLines, -1

InitWinsock() {
VarSetCapacity(wsaData, 32, 0)
result := DllCall("Ws2_32\\WSAStartup", "UShort", 0x0202, "UInt", &wsaData)
if (result != 0) {
MsgBox, Failed to initialize Winsock. Error: %result%
return false
}
return true
}

SendToggleCommand() {
if (!InitWinsock()) {
return
}

    sock := DllCall("Ws2_32\socket", "Int", 2, "Int", 1, "Int", 6)  ; AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP
    if (sock = -1) {
        MsgBox, Failed to create socket.
        return
    }
    
    
    VarSetCapacity(addr, 16, 0)  
    NumPut(2, addr, 0, "UShort")  ; AF_INET
    NumPut(DllCall("Ws2_32\htons", "UShort", 65432), addr, 2, "UShort")
    NumPut(0x0100007F, addr, 4, "UInt") ; ; IP 127.0.0.1:65432
    
    
    result := DllCall("Ws2_32\connect", "UInt", sock, "UInt", &addr, "Int", 16)
    if (result != 0) {
        error_code := DllCall("Ws2_32\WSAGetLastError")  
        MsgBox, Failed to connect to the server. Error: %error_code%
        DllCall("Ws2_32\closesocket", "UInt", sock)
        return
    }
    
    
    toggleStr := "TOGGLE`n"  
    
    
    VarSetCapacity(buffer, StrLen(toggleStr))  ; 
    StrPut(toggleStr, &buffer, StrLen(toggleStr) + 1, "UTF-8")  
    
    
    sendResult := DllCall("Ws2_32\send", "UInt", sock, "Ptr", &buffer, "Int", StrLen(toggleStr), "Int", 0)
    
    
    if (sendResult = StrLen(toggleStr)) {
        ; MsgBox, Data sent successfully!
        OutputDebug, % "Data sent successfully!"
    } else {
        ; MsgBox, Failed to send the complete data.
        OutputDebug, % "Failed to send the complete data.."
    }
    
    
    DllCall("Ws2_32\closesocket", "UInt", sock)
    DllCall("Ws2_32\WSACleanup")

}

; Ctrl+F7
^F7::SendToggleCommand()

then,
i use ahk v2 to try to send socket message (server: 127.0.0.1:65432), like below:
it did send a message, but after about 5-7 times, it crushed. and i don't know how to fix it..

#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

InitWinsock() {
wsaData := Buffer(32, 0)
result := DllCall("Ws2_32\\WSAStartup", "UShort", 0x0202, "Ptr", wsaData.Ptr)
if result != 0 {
MsgBox("Failed to initialize Winsock. Error: " result)
return false
}
return true
}

CleanupWinsock() {
DllCall("Ws2_32\\WSACleanup")
}

SendToggleCommand() {

    if !InitWinsock() {
        return
    }
    
    
    sock := DllCall("Ws2_32\socket", "Int", 2, "Int", 1, "Int", 6)
    if sock = -1 {
        MsgBox("Failed to create socket.")
        CleanupWinsock()
        return
    }
    
    ; 127.0.0.1:65432
    addr := Buffer(16, 0)
    NumPut("UShort", 2, addr, 0)  ; AF_INET
    NumPut("UShort", DllCall("Ws2_32\htons", "UShort", 65432), addr, 2)  )
    NumPut("UInt", 0x0100007F, addr, 4)  ; IP 127.0.0.1
    
    
    result := DllCall("Ws2_32\connect", "Int", sock, "Ptr", addr.Ptr, "Int", addr.Size)
    if result != 0 {
        error_code := DllCall("Ws2_32\WSAGetLastError", "Int")
        MsgBox("Failed to connect to the server. Error: " error_code)
        DllCall("Ws2_32\closesocket", "Int", sock)
        CleanupWinsock()
        return
    }
    
    
    toggleStr := "TOGGLE`n"
    
    utf8Buffer := Buffer(StrPut(toggleStr, "UTF-8") - 1)
    StrPut(toggleStr, utf8Buffer.Ptr, utf8Buffer.Size, "UTF-8")
    
    
    sendResult := DllCall("Ws2_32\send", "Int", sock, "Ptr", utf8Buffer.Ptr, "Int", utf8Buffer.Size, "Int", 0)
    if sendResult = utf8Buffer.Size {
        OutputDebug("Data sent successfully!")
    } else {
        OutputDebug("Failed to send the complete data.")
    }
    
    
    DllCall("Ws2_32\closesocket", "Int", sock)
    
    
    CleanupWinsock()

}

; Ctrl+F7
^F7::SendToggleCommand()


oh, i finally get a version for v2, it works fine...

if you have a working solution, then you should either post an answer or delete the question.
